# How to update document field in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Mongodb so below code i am trying to update document field `string` i have object recieved in post `req.body` now based on `_id` i want to update `string` field but it is not updating record with below implementation. How can i update record using `_id` ? Any better approach to update record in terms of async will be appreciated.

routes.js

```
var Diagram = require('./diagram');
    router.post('/saveUpdateDiagram',function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body._id);
        Diagram.update(req.body);
    });
```

diagram.js

```
  var diagram = require('./diagram.model');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Diagram = {
    index: function(callback) {
        diagram.find({}, function(err, result) {
            if (!err) {
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function(data) {
        console.log('data in controller', data);
        Diagram.update({ $set: { 'string' : data.string  } });
    }
}
module.exports = Diagram;
```

data.json

```
{
    _id: "57fe42efc3590c7686bad563"
    groups: Array[0]
    owner: "sh587"
    string: "test string should be updated"
    text: "gcs_wf_dit.bpmn"
    users: Array[1]

}
```

Comment: post complete `diagram.js` code including `require` modules

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: You should first match the document then update. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/ db.products.update(
   { _id: 100 },
   { $set: { "details.make": "zzz" } }
).. You can pass empty JSON object if you want to update all the documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that JavaScript is case sensitive language you should use **`diagram.update`** not `Diagram.update`

use `diagram.update({ $set: { 'string' : data.string  } });

diagram.js should be

diagram.js

```
var diagram = require('./diagram.model');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Diagram = {
    index: function(callback) {
        diagram.find({}, function(err, result) {
            if (!err) {
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function(data) {
        console.log('data in controller', data);
        diagram.update({_id: data._id}, { $set: { 'string' : data.string  } });
    }
}
module.exports = Diagram;
```

Comment: ok now i used diagram.update but i do not see any activity in monodb `string` field is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "string" field in diagram model. as mongoose allow only those fields which are available in schema. If not then add

```
string: {type: String}
```

and then use

```
var diagram = require('./diagram.model');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Diagram = {
    index: function(callback) {
        diagram.find({}, function(err, result) {
            if (!err) {
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function(data) {
        diagram.update({_id: data._id}, { $set: { 'string' : data.string  } });
    }
}
module.exports = Diagram;
```